# error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '&' token| on a simple C program found online

Tags: c, codeblocks

I found this program online to practice C. When I tried to compile this program in Code blocks, I am getting this error "error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '&' token| " in two places (mentioned in the codes). It would be really helpful, if someone could explain me the reason for the error.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int f1(int x,int y)
{

x=x+2;
y=y+3;
return x+y;}
int f2(int &x,int y) //error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '&' token|

{
 x=x+2;
y=y+3;
return x+y;
}
int f3(int *x,int *y)
{

*x = *x+2;
*y = *y+3;
return *x+*y;
}
int f4(int x,int &y,int *z)//error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '&' token|
{    x=x+y;

 y=*z+3;
z=&x;
*z=y*2;
return *z;
}
main()
{
int k=3,m=5,r=0;
printf("1) %d %d %d\n",k,m,r);
r=f1(k,m);
printf("2) %d %d %d\n",k,m,r);
r=f2(k,m);
printf("1) %d %d %d\n",k,m,r);
r=f3(&k,&m);
printf("1) %d %d %d\n",k,m,r);
r=f4(k,m,&r);
printf("1) %d %d %d\n",k,m,r);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: C does not have C++ references.

Comment: Solved my problem. Thank you very much for all your responses. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a C program. This is a C++ program. It does not use too many C++ features, but it uses enough to make this code non-compilable as C code.

Either compile it as C++ or convert it to C. The latter would require rewriting quite a few lines of that code.

Comment: int f2(int x, int y) thats problems soul

Answer (score 1):

In C you should not use reference In function definition AS like C++.

You do not need to use pointer even, because you are just passing values.

```
int f2(int &x,int y) 
          ^^
```

Modify above function definition

```
 int f2(int x,int y)
```

This line also

```
 int f4(int x,int &y,int *z)
```

Modify above function definition

```
 int f4(int x,int y,int *z)
```

and declare your functions.

Answer (score 1):

Line 11 Should be `int f2(int *x,int y)`

The code you posted is C++ code. Not C code. You can not execute C++ code on C compiler.

Comment: Changing line 11 is certainly not enough to turn this C++ program into into a C program. Quite a few lines of code would have to be corrected as well.

Comment: @AndreyT: Yes you are right. Will update my post.